# How to add 3D authentication in stripe default payment integration in PHP?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe payment gateway in PHP.
Now i want to add 3D authentication in this existing code of stripe integration.

How can i add 3D authentication code? Please help or provide any reference so i can check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you've implemented the [default integration](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder) using the PaymentIntents API, then congrats you already have 3DS authentication enabled! You can now test your integration with a [3DS test card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards).

If you integrated with Stripe using the Charge API, then you'll need to [upgrade your integration](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication/migration) to PaymentIntents before you can make use of the new 3DS features.